# What does the Call keyword do in VB6?

Tags: vba, vb6, syntax

There's some code in our project that looks a bit like this:

```
Private Sub Method1()
    Call InnerMethod
End Sub

Private Sub Method2()
    InnerMethod
End Sub

Private Sub InnerMethod()
    '' stuff
End Sub
```

What's the advantage of doing Method1 over Method2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use Call keyword in VB/VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573597/should-i-use-call-keyword-in-vb-vba)

Comment: No more than the answers to this question, to be honest! Fortunately for me all of that VB code is *long* dead. Even the other question you refer to is from 13 years ago - more than a year after this one was asked! Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcx04ck5(VS.85).aspx):

> You are not required to use the Call
>   keyword when calling a procedure.
>   However, if you use the Call keyword
>   to call a procedure that requires
>   arguments, argumentlist must be
>   enclosed in parentheses. If you omit
>   the Call keyword, you also must omit
>   the parentheses around argumentlist.
>   If you use either Call syntax to call
>   any intrinsic or user-defined
>   function, the function's return value
>   is discarded.

For example:

```
Sub Proc1()
    Debug.Print "Hello World"
End Sub

Sub Proc2(text As String)
    Debug.Print "Hello " & text
End Sub
```

In the immediate window, if you enter

```
Proc1
```

then "Hello World" prints. If you enter

```
Call Proc1
```

then "Hello World" prints. If you enter

```
Proc2 "World"
```

then "Hello World" prints. If you enter

```
Call Proc2 "World"
```

you get a compile error. You would have to enter

```
Call Proc2("World")
```

Answer (score 12):

Call does nothing special other than call the method. It is a hang over from the old days of Basic when all lines had to start with a keyword. "Let" is another of these keywords, which was always put before an assignment, but is no longer required.

Method1 and Method2 do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a major difference about 'call' keyword with functions that having, ByRef Arguments (I have found this in MS-Access VBA editor). If you are calling the function without 'Call' keyword, ByRef aruments will not set for the calle. For Ex:

```
Private Function Test(Optional ByRef refArg As String) As Boolean    
    refArg = "Test"
    Test = True
End Function
```

If you call the function without the `Call` keyword like

```
Dim a As String
Test(a)
```

`a` will be an empty string, after the call returns

If you call the function with the `Call` keyword like

```
Dim a As String
Call Test(a)
```

`a` will contain the string `Test`

The detailed explanation provided in the following link:
[Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/)

Comment: The two are not equivalent. In the first case, enclosing the argument in parens causes it to be evaluated, and the result of the evaluation passed: in essence, you're passing a copy of "a", not "a" itself.

This is made obvious by the parser. When you enter Test(a) and leave the line, the parser will add a space, making it Test (a) to indicate that it's an expression; whereas with Call Test(a) no space will be added -- you're passing "a" directly.

See the answer by Patrick Cuff above for the doc reference.

Comment: Indeed, and actually getting the result (for example, `MsgBox Test(a)`) restores the equivalence.

Comment: You should delete this answer. It is extremely misleading... and wrong. Down-voted. Never call a procedure with parentheses around the argument list... with two exceptions: using the Call keyword or doing an assignment from the result of a function. You are not doing either and so the variable surrounded by parentheses gets evaluated and sent to the procedure as a literal value (not the variable) and since it is no longer a variable, there is no way to get the updated value back. You don't need Call in your example... you just need to remove the parentheses from around the argument: `Test a`

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [post](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=54171) which describes when you need to use call vs not using it and when to parentheses around your parameters.

You can also read more about [call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz(VS.71).aspx) from MSDN. Essentially the main difference is that when you use call to call a function you can't access the return value.