# Highlight and unhighlight specific ranges when a box is clicked

Tags: vba, automation, excel

I am a beginning in visual basic. What I am trying to do is whenever a box is clicked, highlight a specific range. Then, if another box is clicked after that, the previous range will unhighlight, and another range will highlight. Here is my code but it doesn't work right now.

```
Dim FSelect As Boolean
Dim myRange As Range

Sub Rectangle18_Click()

   If FSelect Then
        UnhighlightBox (myRange) <---error - runtime error "424" object required
   End If

   Range("C9:D9").Select
   HighlightBox

   FSelect = True

   Set myRange = Range("C9:D9")
   End Sub

Sub Rectangle19_Click()

   If FSelect Then
        UnhighlightBox (myRange)
   End If

   Range("C11:D11").Select
   HighlightBox

   FSelect = True

   Set myRange = Range("C11:D11")

End Sub    

Sub HighlightBox()
   Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End Sub

Sub UnhighlightBox(cellRng As Range)
   cellRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get on that line? (Also in StackOverflow if you highlight all your code and click the '101' icon next to the quote icon above the post edit box then it will all be displayed as formatted code)

Answer (score 1):

When I throw this code into excel it complains about Select.  I don't think you can use Select as a variable...

EDIT: Select is a reserved keyword in VB/A, It begins the Select Case block.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the parentheses around the argument when calling the UnhighlightBox procedure is incorrect.

Two possible correct forms:

`UnhighlightBox myRange`

`Call UnhighlightBox(myRange)`

I find the first form (without the `Call` keyword) to be preferable

For the Excel 2003 help:

> You are not required to use the Call
>   keyword when calling a procedure.
>   However, if you use the Call keyword
>   to call a procedure that requires
>   arguments, argumentlist must be
>   enclosed in parentheses. If you omit
>   the Call keyword, you also must omit
>   the parentheses around argumentlist.

Please note that this does not apply to a function which returns a value. A function needs to be called as part of an assignment (e.g. `a = f(x)`) and the arguments must be enclosed in parentheses

Your use of the `FSelect` boolean (which initialises to false) should be preventing the problem with calling `UnhighlightBox` before `myRange` is ever set.

Answer (score 0):

When using the UnhighlightBox routine you either need to put the Call statement before hand or remove the parenthesis.

For example:

```
Call UnhighlightBox (myRange)
```

or

```
UnhighlightBox myRange
```

For more info on why to use Call, etc see the either of the following:

[what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479891/what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcx04ck5(VS.85).aspx)