# The Call statement in VBA. Completely Pointless?

Tags: vba

Can anybody give me an example to change my mind?

I've seen this [elswhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413765/what-are-the-rules-governing-usage-of-brackets-in-vba-function-calls/5413977#5413977):

> The purpose of the Call statement when used with a Sub is to allow you
>   to enclose the argument list in parentheses.

That to me is not a valid purpose. It just makes code slightly less readable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573597/should-i-use-call-keyword-in-vb-vba

Comment: There can be side effects of calling a sub with parentheses but without call, so possibly its an attempt to clarify intent? (still a weak reason)

Comment: I hate that calls can be made without the CALL key word and parentheses.

I always include them.

Answer (score 0):

I use the call statement when I am making a method call into some object like a form, where the length of the statement makes it not immediately clear that it is a method call.

```
Call Forms!frmInvoice.Form!UpdateLineItems(taxRate)
```

The argument could be made that making all method calls use parentheses *improves* readability by making all such calls consistent.  Of course, making them all functions instead of subs avoids the problem altogether.