# i loop only goes through first iteration

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm having trouble with my `i` loop. For some reason, my loop only goes through the first iteration (`i=0`) and then stops. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub DeleteFillerRows()

Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim searchRange As Range

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To i = 2
    If i = 0 Then
        lastRow = 1
    End If

    MsgBox (i) 'used for testing, only displays the first i (0)

    Set searchRange = Range("A" & CStr(lastRow) & ":A1000")

    firstRow = searchRange.Find(What:="Name /", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    MsgBox (firstRow)

    lastRow = searchRange.Find(What:="Region 1", LookAt:=xlWhole).Row - 2
    MsgBox (lastRow)
Next i

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me  with this? I feel dumb asking about a simple i loop but I just can't see where I could have gone wrong.

Comment: `For i = 0 To  2`

Comment: @ScottCraner you're a life saver, you know that? You deserve like fifty gold medals.

Comment: While you're at it, change the integers to long.  They're stored as Long anyway, and it takes extra time (about 42 picoseconds, but still) to change them.

Comment: Great to know @Hrothgar. I'm all about efficiency!

Comment: Also, drop the parentheses around the `MsgBox` argument list. [This habit will end up biting you in the rear end](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42121272/1188513)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `For` loop is bounded like this:

`For <counter> = <start> To <end>`

In your case, `<counter>` is the variable `i`, `<start>` is `0`, and `<end>` is the expression `i = 2`.

The reason why it only executes once is because the expression `i = 2` evaluates as a `Boolean`, and it's always false because the initializer for the loop sets it to `0` (which is `False`).

If you rewrite your code with parentheses for grouping, it is a lot clearer what is going on:

`For i = 0 To (i = 2)`

...becomes...

`For i = 0 To False`

...which is...

`For i = 0 To 0`

As @ScottCraner correctly points out in the comments, simply correct the line to:

`For i = 0 to 2`