# VBA Call method with optional parameters

Tags: vba, call

I just figured out that setting optional parameters requires "Call" infront of the method.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Call abc("aaa")
    Call abc("aaa", 2)

    abc("aaa") ' is fine
    abc("aaa", 2) ' is a syntax error

End Sub


Function abc(a As String, Optional iCol As Long = 3)

    MsgBox (iCol)

End Function
```

Can you add a "why does this make sense?" to my new information?

Greetings,
Peter

Edit: PS the function abc for no other use than to simplify the question.

Comment: There are some nice examples and explanations about when `Call` *can* and *can't* be used below but the fact is: **there is virtually no reason to use it** -- with [one small exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573597/should-i-use-call-keyword-in-vb-vba#comment19036905_2573597). So just avoid until completely necessary.

Comment: The accepted answer skirts your question. YOU DO NOT need to use "Call" to set optional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Documentation

`Call` is an optional keyword, but the one caveat is that if you use it you must include the parentheses around the arguments, but if you omit it you must not include the parentheses.

Quote from MSDN:

> You are not required to use the Call keyword when calling a procedure.
>
> **However, if you use the Call keyword to call a procedure that requires arguments, argumentlist must be enclosed in parentheses. If you omit the Call keyword, you also must omit the parentheses around argumentlist.** If you use either Call syntax to call any intrinsic or user-defined function, the function's return value is discarded.
>
> To pass a whole array to a procedure, use the array name followed by empty parentheses.

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251710.aspx

---

## In Practice

This means that the following syntaxes are allowed:

```
Call abc("aaa")
Call abc("aaa", 2)
abc "aaa", 2
abc("aaa") ' <- Parantheses here do not create an argument list
abc(((("aaa")))) ' <- Parantheses here do not create an argument list
```

The following syntaxes are not allowed:

```
Call abc "aaa", 2
abc("aaa", 2) ' <- Parantheses here create an argument list
```

---

## Function Return Values

This doesn't take effect when using a function to get a return value, for example if you were to do the following you need parentheses:

```
Function abc(a As String, Optional iCol As Long = 3)
    abc = iCol
End Function

'## IMMEDIATE WINDOW ##
?abc("aaa", 2)      'this works
?abc "aaa, 2        'this will not work
?Call abc "aaa", 2  'this will not work
?Call abc("aaa", 2) 'this will not work
```

If you are using `Call` on a `Function` then consider changing it to a `Sub` instead, functions are meant to return a value as in the cases above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim strText As String

    strText = "E"
    Call Abc(strText, 3)
    Call Abc(strText, 2)

    Abc (strText)
'    Abc (strtext,5)

    Abc strText, 2
    Abc strText


End Sub

Public Sub Abc(strText As String, Optional iCol As Long = 5)

    Debug.Print iCol

End Sub
```

Absolutely no idea why the commented code does not work...

Answer (score 0):

`Call` is an optional keyword, as already described in detailed in the answer above.

for your second option

```
abc("aaa", 2) ' is a syntax error
```

Just use:

```
abc "aaa", 2
```

---

**Note**: there is little use to have a `Function` if you don't return anything, you could have a regular `Sub` instead.

to have a `Function` that return a `String` for instance (just something made-up quick):

```
Function abc(a As String, Optional iCol As Long = 3) As String                    
    abc = a & CStr(iCol)        
End Function
```

and then call it:

```
Public Sub Test()

    d = abc("aaa", 2)
    MsgBox d

End Sub
```

Comment: Because the paretheses don't do anything when there's only one value, it's not creating an argument list it's encapsulating what is inside to one value. To demonstrate, this will also work: `abc ((((("aaa")))))`