# Array string not able to pass through to 'Worksheets'

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to set up a code which essentially looks at an array of worksheets, and perform the exact same check for each of those. Unfortunately I seem to be getting the following message anytime I try to access the With... function (through which I would like the array to operate):

> Run-time error '9': Subscription out of range

Although the variable

> WshtNames(w)

does end up taking the name required, it cannot seem to store it so that it can be applied to the respective worksheet? Any help greatly appreciated. Code below:

```
    Option Explicit

Public Cell, WshtNames As Variant, Check_Tab, Bench_OAS_Level, Bench_OAS_Change, Bench_Spread_Dur, Bench_Duration, Bench_Convexity, ws As Worksheets, FirstHeaderColumn, LRow, LastRow As Long

Sub Definitions()

Set Bench_OAS_Level = Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018").Worksheets("Bench OAS Level")
Set Bench_OAS_Change = Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018").Worksheets("Bench OAS Change")
Set Bench_Spread_Dur = Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018").Worksheets("Bench Spread Dur")
Set Bench_Duration = Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018").Worksheets("Bench Duration")
Set Bench_Convexity = Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018").Worksheets("Bench Convexity")
Set Check_Tab = Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018").Worksheets("Check")

End Sub

Sub Check_OOT()

Call Definitions

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim CalcRange, FirstHeaderRow, LastColumn As Range
Dim w As Long

WshtNames = Array("Bench_OAS_Level", "Bench_OAS_Change", "Bench_Spread_Dur", "Bench_Duration", "Bench_Convexity")

For w = LBound(WshtNames) To UBound(WshtNames)

  With Worksheets(WshtNames(w))

    Set LastColumn = .UsedRange.Find("Total", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set FirstHeaderRow = .UsedRange.Find("Level 1", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    FirstHeaderColumn = FirstHeaderRow.Column + 2
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, LastColumn.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    Set CalcRange = .Range(.Cells(FirstHeaderRow.Row + 2, FirstHeaderRow.Column + 3), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn.Column))

       For Each Cell In CalcRange
          If Not IsError(Cell) Then
           If Cell > 500 Or Cell < -100 Then
           Cell.Font.Bold = True
           Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
           Cell.EntireRow.Copy
              Call Copy_into_Check_Tab
           End If
        End If
       Next Cell

  End With

Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: could you upload a screenshot of just the worksheet tab names on your screen?

Comment: The exact names are in the Sub_Definitions, referenced as each worksheet.

Comment: I see them written out but based on the problems with the current answers it seems like they're trying to access a worksheet that is spelled wrong/ doesnt exist/etc and a picture *might* clear things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the names of the worksheets are:

- Bench OAS Level
- Bench OAS Change
- Bench Spread Dur
- Bench Duration
- Bench Convexity

But that you're storing them in the array as:

- Bench_OAS_Level
- Bench_OAS_Change
- Bench_Spread_Dur
- Bench_Duration
- Bench_Convexity

(with underscores).

Does this fix the problem?

Also, it might be helpful to add a dictionary object to the public scope:

```
public worksheetDictionary as object
```

And change the definitions code to:

```
Sub Definitions()
    set worksheetDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018")
        Call worksheetDictionary.Add("Bench_OAS_Level", .Worksheets("Bench OAS Level"))
        Call worksheetDictionary.Add("Bench_OAS_Change",.Worksheets("Bench OAS Change"))
        Call worksheetDictionary.Add("Bench_Spread_Dur", .Worksheets("Bench Spread Dur"))
        Call worksheetDictionary.Add("Bench_Duration", .Worksheets("Bench Duration"))
        Call worksheetDictionary.Add("Bench_Convexity", .Worksheets("Bench Convexity"))

        Set Check_Tab = Workbooks("TEST Overview Tool Barclays May 2018").Worksheets("Check")
    End With
End Sub
```

Then, you'd change the for loop in your main block to start like this:

```
For each k in worksheetDictionary.Keys
    With worksheetDictionary(k)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't use `Call`, it is now deprecated.

Comment: Can you point me towards some MSDN documentation for that? I always thought it was a stylistic thing, and I prefer to use Call in my code. If it's deprecated, I should probably stop though. The only thing I found was [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/call-statement), which mentions that they're optional but no more. @AJD

Comment: @ChipR. that is awesome! Thanks so much mate. Great insight on the dictionary too

Comment: @ChipR. MSDN documentation aint what it used to be! The newer pages don't have the discussion they used to have about it being for backwards compatibility and is now deprecated. I also remember a discussion somewhere (linked from some answer here on SO) about how Call and () can affect how parameters are passed in some circumstances.

Comment: @ChipR.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573597/should-i-use-call-keyword-in-vb-vba

Comment: @AJD. Thanks for the response. Interesting about the deprecation; I'll definitely keep my eye out for that. And, yes, re: Call and () parameters is exactly why I use call all the time for my subroutine calls. The short version is: I like having input parameters inside () always, and NOT using the "Call" keyword means you have to put parameters outside parens, after a space from the subroutine name, and delimited by commas, which I think is clunky. Using Call with all subroutines allows me to always put input parameters inside parens.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing...

```
Dim CalcRange, FirstHeaderRow, LastColumn As Range
Dim w As Long

WshtNames = Array("Bench_OAS_Level", "Bench_OAS_Change", "Bench_Spread_Dur", "Bench_Duration", "Bench_Convexity")

 For w = LBound(WshtNames) To UBound(WshtNames)

     With Worksheets(WshtNames(w))
```

To...

```
Dim CalcRange, FirstHeaderRow, LastColumn As Range
Dim w As variant

WshtNames = Array("Bench_OAS_Level", "Bench_OAS_Change", "Bench_Spread_Dur", "Bench_Duration", "Bench_Convexity")

 Foreach w in wshtNames

     With Worksheets(w)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I tried as you said but unfortunately still having the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure the worksheet names in the array are correct?!

Comment: yeah the names seem to be correct cause if I use With and the names themselves the macro works fine. I believe as Doug pointed out below that it is a reference to the 'Worksheets..'

Answer (score 1):

When using UBound and LBound you must use the second parameter to tell the compiler which dimension of the array that youre wanting to loop through.

```
 example:  For w = LBound(WshtNames,1) To UBound(WshtNames,1)
```

or

```
 example: For w = LBound(WshtNames,2) To UBound(WshtNames,2)
```

Youre getting out of range b.c the compiler doesnt knwo what/where youre trying to tell it to go.

I ran this for fun and works as expected

[image]

Here is the proper way to address setting workbook values

```
WshtNames = Array("Bench_OAS_Level", "Bench_OAS_Change", "Bench_Spread_Dur", "Bench_Duration", "Bench_Convexity")

set wb = Workbooks(“workbookname.filextension”)

For w = LBound(WshtNames) To UBound(WshtNames)

  With wb.Worksheets(WshtNames(w))
```

Comment: thanks very much, that was very helpful. Unfortunately the subscription still seems out of range, even when I input the dimensions (1 or 2 as you highlighted for example). Any idea why that may be the case?

Comment: If it is on the line "With Worksheets(WshtNames(w))"  it might be due to the fact youre not referencing which workbook contains said sheet. What I would do i set which workbook youre in and then reference wb.Sheets(WshtNames(w)). Make sense?

Comment: Or loop through sheets. Same end different approach

Comment: Yes it is exactly where you're pointing out that it breaks. I have now declared wb and set it = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WshtNames(w)) but unfortunately it still throws that annoying out of range! I've declared wb as worksheet, workbook etc but still same issue. Driving me nuts!

Comment: @ChefTony does that fix your issue and things run accordingly?

Comment: referenced as pointed out but issue still there...thank you so much for your help though!