# Call keyword - deprecated or not

Tags: vba

[image]

I have seen over the time people mentioning that the **Call Statement** is deprecated, but I can't seem to find anything official to support this claim.

On the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement), there was a pretty recent update to the page (*12/03/2018*), so can't really say is outdated information.

I've been using Call in my code, most of the time simply because I find this:

`Call function(arg1, arg2, arg3)`
to be more readable than 
`function arg1, arg2, arg3`

*Now for the **question**, can anyone provide some insight into why I shouldn't use the `Call` statement anymore?* If you do say is deprecated, please do provide a link to a resource.

If this question is against the site rules, please do let me know, I`ll happily delete it myself, though would be nice to get answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's deprecated, it's just not required which may have led people to believe that it is never needed... which is technically [not true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325284/11683).

Comment: That being said, it does come out as old fashioned. I personally dislike it and would become more suspicious about code that uses it extensively. It would make me feel like I should now check that code more carefully for techniques that worked well 20 years ago but should really be done differently nowadays.

Comment: My comments on the previous question that prompted this question, should have been included in your question. I won't repost what I already have.

Comment: Certainly not deprecated, it got more useful in vb.net.  Which btw also got rid of the awkward distinction between invoking a Sub vs a Function.  Most practical usage in vba that I can think of is that you make it much more obvious that not using the return value of a Function was intentional.  It removes a code smell.

Comment: I find the documentation from Microsoft is getting blander. Once upon a time, these documents also included hints and context for getting the best out of the functions and routines, as well as contra-indications for using it. Now it simply states what the function is supposed to do. That page also used to note that the `Call` keyword was deprecated and only remained for backwards compatibility. It is no longer an 'Office Dev Centre' but a VBA 101 for numpties. I did once post a couple of links either here or SuperUser which officially stated that Call was deprecated but I can't find them.

Comment: Consider this code `Sub Main:4:Msgbox "Hello":Goto 4:End Sub`. Because it support old standards doesn't mean you should program like this. `:` is the same as enter.

Comment: I use `:` quite often, especially when declaring and assigning values to variables immediately after. There aren't many `new` standards in VBA, so not quite sure what's wrong with using the `old` standards.

Comment: I was referring to *line numbers* and `goto`.

Comment: @AJD learn.microsoft.com is open-source and [hosted on github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs) - the VBA docs is ~35K individual documents (can't recall if that's just Excel or all of VBA docs), and it's very actively maintained, with several changes merged every day. If you see something wrong or missing in the docs, submit a PR, or open an issue!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Not so much what is "wrong", but what is disappearing with each evolution! But I don't have time to get into memory wars (I remember this ... but someone else then argues its importance or not).

Comment: @AJD as a "watcher" I receive email notifications for every single bit of activity on the VBA docs repository; if I see a discussion come up around deprecated/obsolete statements, I'll definitely weight in. In fact, this whole thread is extremely motivating for one particular personal project of mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try to avoid the `Call` (and thus, it is depreciated for me) for the following reason - in #VBA I consider passing a variable in parenthesis as a way to overrun the standard `ByVal`/`ByRef` specification of the parameters. What do I mean? Consider this example:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim var1 As Long: var1 = 1
    Dim var2 As Long: var2 = 1

    IncrementByVal (var1)
    IncrementByRef (var2)

    Debug.Print var1, var2

End Sub

Public Function IncrementByVal(ByVal a As Variant) As Variant
    a = a + 100
    IncrementByVal = a
End Function

Public Function IncrementByRef(ByRef a As Variant) As Variant
    a = a + 100
    IncrementByRef= a
End Function
```

As you probably see, both `var1` and `var2` return `1`, while the `var2` should be `101`, as far as it is `ByRef`. The `Call`-word kind-of improves this "feature" in VBA, but it becomes too complicated to remember when the parenthesis are overriding the `ByRef` and when not, when reading code. Thus, having 3 cases is quite a lot:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim var1 As Long: var1 = 1
    Dim var2 As Long: var2 = 1
    Dim var3 As Long: var3 = 1
    Dim var4 As Long: var4 = 1
    Dim var5 As Long: var5 = 1
    Dim var6 As Long: var6 = 1

    IncrementByVal (var1)           '1
    IncrementByRef (var2)           '1
    IncrementByVal var3             '1
    IncrementByRef var4             '101
    Call IncrementByVal(var5)       '1
    Call IncrementByRef(var6)       '101

    Debug.Print var1, var2
    Debug.Print var3, var4
    Debug.Print var5, var6

End Sub

Public Function IncrementByVal(ByVal a As Variant) As Variant
    a = a + 100
    IncrementByVal = a
End Function

Public Function IncrementByRef(ByRef a As Variant) As Variant
    a = a + 100
    IncrementByRef = a
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Vityata, I think you've meant `a = a + 100` in the functions (for `ByRef` at least).  I like the point you are making, but still think is less confusing using `Call` then not (as long you never just use `function (args)`). I can see however why some people would think is deprecated, given is being frown upon.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer this, after taking in consideration other comments as well, your answer did gave me the clarity I was looking for.

Comment: "it becomes too complicated to remember when the parenthesis are overriding the ByRef and when not, when reading code" - only until you understand how the language works, or at least, [implicit] call statements. Until then, `Call` is nothing but a crutch ...that actually hinders this understanding. Curious what you think of my answer, and what a shame this question was asked on a Saturday morning! I almost missed it!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - it was almost a month ago, good job in checking stuff :)

Comment: You are conflating the brackets around parameters required by `Call`, and using brackets to overrive `ByRef`.  They are not they same thing, and one has nothing to do with the other.  This is demonstrated by your missing use of Call: `Call IncrementByRef((var6))` would process `ByVal`

Answer (score 22):

## Consistency is King

Whether you're calling a `Sub` or a `Function` makes no difference whatsoever. What matters is **consistency**, and *that's* what `Call`-lovers claim using the keyword brings. Consistency with whether or not parentheses are required around the argument list.

So instead of this simple-as-it-gets implicit call statement:

```
MsgBox "I'm a function but you're discarding my return value, so no parentheses."
```

We get things like this:

```
MsgBox ("I'm a function but you're discarding my return value, and this call looks weird.")
```

And I've yet to see the `Call` *actually* being used with any kind of *actual consistency*:

```
Call MsgBox("I'm a function but you're discarding my return value, so I have a Call keyword.")
Call MyProcedure(42)
Call ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10").Clear
Call Beep
Call CallByName(obj, "SomeMethod", VbCalType.VbMethod)
```

Used consistently, `Call` quickly becomes obnoxious, clearly redundant, and *slows down reading*, because the eyes can't help but stop on the keyword, and then the brain goes "oh hey watch out, we're calling something here". I suppose at one point you just stop seeing it, and just feel like something's off if it's missing.

The overwhelming majority of *every single executable statement* is going to be a call to something, somewhere, at some abstraction level - using `Call` consistently makes the language even more heavily bulky than it already is.

Unless `Call` isn't *really* about consistency, more about *being able to easily see my own user procedure calls*... which at this point is just grasping at straws to legitimize an archaic construct that serves no purpose whatsoever: **there is no legitimate use for the `Call` keyword**.

This is the only "legit" use case:

```
Public Sub Test()
DoSomething: DoSomethingElse
'vs.
'Call DoSomething: Call DoSomethingElse
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething() '<~ dead code. can you see why?
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingElse()
End Sub
```

The `Call` keyword disambiguates a `LineLabel:` from a `ParameterlessProcedureCall` followed by an `:` instruction separator. Only problem is, `:` instruction separators are great for golfing and cramming as much executable code as possible on a single line of code ...they are terrible for readability. Besides everybody agrees that a `NEWLINE` should follow a `;` in any semicolon-terminated language, *even though it makes perfect sense for the compiler to ignore the line jump*.

We write code for people to read and maintain, not just for compilers to build and run.

---

## Deprecated? Says who?

Says [me and my ducky](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ObsoleteCallStatement).

I'm 100% certain I've read in the Official docs at one point in my life, that the keyword was obsolete. Heck, it's even [*specified* as being redundant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/f7c864a8-8fce-49dc-8347-30dc749d6576). Languages evolve, VBA is no exception - even with mind-blowingly incredible levels backward-compatibility and after two decades without any kind of significant changes, the language - or rather, *its practices* are still fluid, even if its maintainers have <s>retired</s> vowed to *just let it be*.

`Call` isn't the only deprecated token in VBA, but for questionable subjective reasons not unsimilar to what people use to justify clinging to [the formidable mistake that *Systems Hungarian* notation was](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) in this century, its roots run deep.

Where are the defenders of the `Rem` comment marker? Why is `While...Wend` still a thing when `Do While...Loop` supersedes it? Is anyone raising errors with the `Error` statement rather than through `Err.Raise`? Outputting error messages with `Error$` rather than through `Err.Description`? Declaring variable types with the ever-so-legible `$&%^!#` type hints? Who writes `On Local Error`? Why use `Global` for things that are really `Public`?

And if explicit `Call` isn't obsolete and "makes the code more readable", then why aren't the same people using explicit `Let` statements for value assignments for the exact same explicitness/clarity reasons?

I think it's well past time to rewrite what the best practices are, and leave `Call` in the past, along with `Let`, Hungarian Notation, and walls-of-declarations at the top of procedures. Every single programming community did this already - only the VBA community is still holding on to the "best practices" from 30 years ago, for brand new code, not just legacy stuff written in another era. I suspect it's very much possible that [VBA's "dread score"](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted) has a lot to do with that, even without taking the bare-bones IDE into account.

I'd love to be able to pull a reference from fellow Microsoft MVP old-timers Rob Bovey and Stephen Bullen, and say "here, see, page 172 it says *the call keyword is obsolete*" ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325284/1188513) seems to mention a "two inch thick book on VBA basically says don't use it unless you want to use the Find feature of the VBE to easily find calls in large projects"), so this might be it, but in any case at the time these gurus essentially defined what the best practices were, "refactoring" was a foreign word, "unit testing" was an *extreme programming* crazy idea - the entire programming landscape has enormously evolved in the past 20 years, but VBA stood still. Time to end this, and move on forward.

Speaking of *moving forward*...

#### "It makes it easier to migrate to VB.NET"

Allegedly, using `Call` statements make it "easier" to port the code to .NET, because VB.NET will want the parentheses everywhere. Respectfully, that's bullocks. First because what you'll want to port your VBA code to isn't VB.NET but much more likely TypeScript, if any kind of porting is ever *actually* going to happen. If you're manually copying VBA code and "translating it" to get it to compile in the target language, you'll quickly find that not having to deal with parentheses is a very marginal perk, since literally everything else needs to be rewritten, ...including *dropping* the `Call` tokens.

Writing small, specialized procedures that do very few things if ever more than a single one, leveraging abstraction levels and classes/objects, reducing coupling *between* modules, improving cohesion *within* modules, having your code's behavior covered and documented with thorough unit tests, **that** will help you port your VBA code faster, and ensure the ported code works identically. `Call` and parentheses are just an excuse to keep a bad habit going.

Comment: Consistency is definitely important, especially in arguents and parenthesis, exactly one of the reasons to "break" Python2 and make it uncompatible with Python3. Good points for `On Local Error` and `Error$`, never used/seen them (and obviously for a reason). I feel the same for the migration to `VB.NET`, I cannot imagine a real-scenario, where the task is to simply copy+paste VBA to VB.NET and to hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently use `Call` when I'm refactoring code or cutting new code I'm not yet sure of.  To explain, using `Call` requires brackets around the arguments and so does returning a value from a function.  I might want to return a value from a function, or I might want to pass an argument by reference (`ByRef`)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim v

    '* Call requires brackets
    Call NotSureIfThisWillEndUpAsASubOrAFunction(1, 2)

    '* return a value from a Function then need brackets
    v = NotSureIfThisWillEndUpAsASubOrAFunction(1, 2)

    '* if always a sub then no brackets required
    WillAlwaysBeASub 4, 5

    '* but is this really so ugly, why deprecate this?
    Call WillAlwaysBeASub(4, 5)

End Sub

Function NotSureIfThisWillEndUpAsASubOrAFunction(a, b)

End Function

Sub WillAlwaysBeASub(c, d)

End Sub
```

EDIT: I think using brackets all the time (which means using `Call` as a keyword for Subs) means less time hopping around the code taking brackets out and then putting them back in upon change of mind.

Comment: I don't see how `Call NotSureIfThisWillEndUpAsASubOrAFunction(1, 2)` is any better than `NotSureIfThisWillEndUpAsASubOrAFunction 1, 2`. Neither tells you whether you are calling a sub or a function, and both discard the return value if there is one.

Comment: Thank you @S Meaden, I know how to use it, was just wondering on what basis people are saying is deprecated, and I'm coming to the conclusion that is only because is been around for long time, and is becoming is less popular. But... not deprecated.

Comment: @FAB: Yeah, sorry, I have reread your question.  I'm on your side, there is nothing wrong with `Call`.