# Shell command does not return the correct result

Tags: vba, command-line

In my program I want to do the following command:

```
RetVal = Shell("dir > temp", 1)
```

When I do that I get the following error:

> Run-time error "53": File not found.

Just doing `Shell("dir", 1)` gives me the same error.  However, if I do `Shell("help", 1)`, it works.

The `dir > temp` command works fine in the command window. I tried using Shell with the following commands: `dir`, `cd`, `ver`, `time`, `date`, `help`.  The only one of these that works is `help`.

I expect to get a directory listing when I do `Shell("dir > temp", 1)` that I can do other things with temp.  Instead, I get "File not found".

Comment: Assuming (dangerously) that you really mean `dir > temp`, you may want to specify a full path for `temp`. Where the file ends up when running from a command prompt may be different than where it ends up when being executed by your VBA code. It never hurts to be fully explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Not all commands passed to the `Shell` function will work as it does in the Command Prompt window. The [`Shell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) function is meant to **run an executable file**, not execute commands:

> Runs an executable program and returns a Variant (Double) representing
>   the program's task ID if successful; otherwise, it returns zero.

Think about it like the "Run" utility in Windows.

What you should do is call "cmd.exe" first and pass whatever arguments/commands you need to it. Try something like this:

```
Dim myCommand As String
myCommand = "dir"
Shell "cmd.exe /S /K" & myCommand, vbNormalFocus
```

If you want the Command Prompt window to close after executing the command, you can replace the parameter `/K` with `/C`. In that case, you might also want to use `vbHide` instead of `vbNormalFocus`:

```
myCommand = "dir > temp"
Shell "cmd.exe /S /C" & myCommand, vbHide
```

Comment: Or simply, `Shell "cmd.exe /S /K" & myCommand, vbNormalFocus` - unless you also do `Call MsgBox("message")` and `Call Beep` and `Call DoEvents`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I don't :-) The OP just used braces in their examples so I didn't want to confuse him/her. After a second thought, `Call` in itself could be more confusing, so you're right! Also, I just noticed that he/she assigns the returned value to a variable so braces should work anyway.

Comment: Nah, I just have [this particular thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874163/1188513) with `Call` never being used *consistently* by anyone that ever uses it ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That's a very informative answer. Thank you!