# VBA Code To Use Macro.A In Workbook.A On Workbook.B.WorkSheet1 Without 'Opening' It

Tags: excel, vba

[Link To Files](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsImeLMHQa7l-kzG8TxPzIXgWz-h?e=m1YEaa)

The First File ConvertToMacroEnabledWorkbook.xlsm because initially I though is was because the file originally come as .xls and not macro enabled so I found a script that converts them to xlsm files. This file also contains the Macro to format the second file DailyReport_Canada.xlsm. is=t doesn't have the macro, but I need to excute the macro from ConvertToMacroEnabledWorkbook.xlsm onto DailyReport_Canada.xlsm.

The Second file is the file to formal as stated in the first paragraph.

I have a Macro.A that applies formatting and I want to be able to apply this formatting to a predefined workbook that contains no macros so I need to execute Macro.A in Workbook.A on Workbook.B

An help is greatful. I have have dabbled in VBA for a while and usually find a solution, but this one I have had for the first time ask for help.

Thank You in Advance

Linked Code To Button Workbook.A:

```
Sub Open_External_Workbook()

Dim FormatMyInvoice As Workbook

Set FormatMyInvoice = Workbooks.Open("C:\Scatchpad\FTL\Excel\_RigDailyReport_Canada.xlsm")

Application.Run "'" & FormatMyInvoice & "'!FormatCostSheet"

End Sub
```

Macro.A Inside Workbook.A

```
Sub FormatCostSheet()
'
' FormatCostSheet Macro
'

'
    Rows("3:3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Rows("3:71").Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 32
    Range("Y36:Z37").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 36
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("T8:T35").Select
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
    Range("R9:R35").Select
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 22
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Range("T9:T35").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 22
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll make life a lot easier for yourself if you [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated after checking the files**

There is no need to use `Application.Run` to run a code from the same workbook. Just `Call` the `Sub` you need, just don't forget to activate the target workbook that needs be formatted first.

```
Sub Open_External_Workbook()
  Dim FormatMyInvoice As Workbook
  Set FormatMyInvoice = Workbooks.Open("Z:\OneDrive-2022-07-03\DailyReport_Canada.xls")
  FormatMyInvoice.Activate
  Call FormatCostSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: It's that What I have already? And it doesn't work. It open the other workbook and should apply the macro yes, but getting a 400 error

Comment: Currently, I see `Application.Run "'" & FormatMyInvoice & "'!FormatCostSheet"` in your code and `FormatMyInvoice` is the new workbook you open but it doesn't contain any macros. In other words, to run a macro via `Application.Run`, you need to specify the name of the workbook that contains it.

Comment: The Macro is not in the target workbook

Comment: Now it looks like `FormatCostSheet` lives in `_RigDailyReport_Canada.xlsm` workbook (which is `Workbook.B` as far as I understand), but you wrote that `Open_External_Workbook` and `FormatCostSheet` are located in `Workbook.A`

Comment: @BrunoBrottes, can you provide those workbooks?

Comment: See post, files are linked at the top of the post to Microsoft SkyDrive

Comment: @BrunoBrottes, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thats Works...thanks You. Working on my next problem...

Comment: Here I posted the completed version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849292/how-i-made-a-workbook-that-executes-a-macro-onto-another-workbook-and-mines-some

Comment: FWIW, use of the `Call` keyword is not required.   [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56874163)