# Reducing Select statements in for loop

Tags: excel, vba, goto

**Does any functionality in vba exist where I can essentially index methods in a loop rather than index matching them??**

I want to avoid repeating the for loop many times as it will make the code messy as other stuff happens in the for loop before the method is applied

See below example for better explanation...

```
For iRow = 1 to LargeNumber
 'do lots of stuff here...
 '...........
 'to here....

Select Method

Case Method1
Call ApplyMethod1

Case Method2
Call ApplyMethod2

.......

Case Methodn
Call ApplyMethodn

end select

next iRow
```

**However the method is known in advance and doesn't need to be found for every row. So more efficiently I could apply something like so (If the functionality existed!).**

```
For iRow = 1 to LargeNumber
 'do lots of stuff here...
 '...........
 'to here....

goto Method

:Method1
Call ApplyMethod1
goto EndOfMethods

:Method2
Call ApplyMethod2
goto EndOfMethods
.......

:Methodn
Call ApplyMethodn
goto EndOfMethods

:EndOfMethods

end select

next iRow
```

Comment: Is there any similarity between the Method1. Method2, etc.

Comment: Side note: though used frequently, `Call` is often regarded as obsolete. - See [`Call` keyword - deprecated or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504639/call-keyword-deprecated-or-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @user3598756 's class approach, you might profit from

- coding a [`Run` procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run) needing an input *string* to define the wanted proc name,
- using an enumeration with invisible elements (within brackets) and a maximum definition for a possible loop:

**Example code within module head**

```
Option Explicit

Enum apply
    [_Start] = 0
    Method1
    Method2
    Method3
    [_Limit]
    max = [_Limit] - 1
End Enum
```

**Note** that enumerations increment empty numeric values by +1 added to the non-defined predecessors.

**Main procedure calling a sequence of enumerated procedures**

```
Sub TestRun()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = apply.Method1 To apply.max
        Run "ApplyMethod" & i     ' << execute "methods" one by one
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Sub ApplyMethod1(Optional ApplyIndex As Long = 1)
    Debug.Print "ApplyMethod" & ApplyIndex
    ' further stuff
    ' ...
End Sub
Sub ApplyMethod2(Optional ApplyIndex As Long = 2)
    Debug.Print "ApplyMethod" & ApplyIndex
    ' further stuff
    ' ...
End Sub
Sub ApplyMethod3(Optional ApplyIndex As Long = 3)
    Debug.Print "ApplyMethod" & ApplyIndex
    ' further stuff
    ' ...
End Sub
```

---

If you prefer a more direct code **without** the additional *enumeration variables*, it suffices to loop as follows:

```
Option Explicit                   ' code module head

Sub TestRun()                     
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3                ' << change 3 to actual maximum
        Run "ApplyMethod" & i     ' << execute "methods" one by one
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice shot +. And without the use of the enumeration it's simpler than the class approach. You may want to write a preface where you show CamalotCoder that he can simply go "Run method"

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the most optimal solution for my use, great job!

Answer (score 1):

use the `CallByName()` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function), which requires an object to call the methods of

hence you need to add a class that collects all the needed methods

add a class module, give it a name (I named it "clMethods")

add this code to the class module

```
Option Explicit

Sub a()
    Debug.Print "a"
End Sub

Sub b()
    Debug.Print "b"
End Sub

Sub c()
    Debug.Print "b"
End Sub
```

in your code use

```
Dim methods_ As clMethods
    Set methods_ = New clMethods
    
    CallByName methods_, "a", VbMethod
```

Comment: You beated me by using a class; might be interested in my tricky enumeration solution, too :+)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Improved my knowledge of class methods which I am sure ill apply in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common 'design pattern' in the land of software design.

In VBA the cleanest way to do this is with a dictionary and a set of small classes that expose a single exec method.

You load a dictionary with pairs of key values and a new instance of the class that has the method that is linked to the key (or if you understand how, a class with a predeclaredid).

If your dictionary is called 'myMethods' and your method selector is called 'myMethod' you can then just use

```
myMethods.Item(myMethod).exec
```

This is the base level for this kind of activity.  You can be more sophisticated by providing initalisation parameters at the new stage etc.