# VBA - Why does this code need the 'CALL' Statement

Tags: vba, class, call

I have the following code which is doing some collecting of data from webpages.  My questions is why does the code 'work' as I expect with the 'CALL' statement, but doesn't work without it...

```
    Dim matchURL            As String
    Dim FixtureDetailsTab   As HTMLTable

    For Each match In FixtureCollection
        matchURL = match.getMatchURL
    '
    '  Load up the match table
    '
        oXML.Open "GET", matchURL, False
        oXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        oXML.send

        Set htmlDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body
        htmlBody.innerHTML = oXML.responseText
    '
    '  And once again look for the elements with class 'engineTable'
    '  (only interested in the first one)
    '
        Set Elements = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("engineTable")
        For Each element In Elements
            Set FixtureDetailsTab = element
            Exit For
        Next element

        Call match.addDetails(FixtureDetailsTab)

    Next match
```

match is a custom class in a separate Class Module, and  'addDetails' is defined as follows

```
    Public Sub addDetails(detailTab As HTMLTable)
        ....
    End Sub
```

The code above works, but if I remove the call statement and just try and invoke the Sub as below

```
    match.addDetails (FixtureDetailsTab)
```

I get 'Run time error 13'  - Type mismatch

I'm puzzled.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the Call keyword do in VB6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479891/what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function/sub in VBA, there are two alternatives:

1. Use CALL and enclose the argument list in parentheses

   ```
    CALL MySub(param1, param2, param3)
   ```
2. Or omit CALL and omit the parentheses

   ```
    MySub param1, param2, param3
   ```

Any of the parameters may be an expression, that itself includes or is enclosed in parentheses:

```
MySub param1, (param2 + 2), param3
```

In your example without CALL, you are passing a single parameter, which is an expression enclosed in parentheses:

```
match.addDetails (FixtureDetailsTab)
```

In VBA, [enclosing an object in parentheses will typically return the default property of that object](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).

Hence you are attempting to pass the default property of FixtureDetailsTab to your method, resulting in a type mismatch.

If you add the CALL statement, the parentheses are interpreted as part of the CALL syntax, and the `FixtureDetailsTab` is passed as an argument, as you'd expect.

Such charming inconsistencies are part of the reason why [VB is loved so much](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/thirteen-ways-to-loathe-vb/184403996?queryText=verity%2Bstob).

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Joe for a very clear explanation - I'm puzzled no more