# invalid outside procedure when using Dim

Tags: vba, excel

I get "invalid outside procedure" error with the following code. Could someone please tell me where I go wrong here.

```
Dim Asset As String, AssetURL As String

Asset = Range("B1").Value

If Asset = "1" Then
    AssetURL = "X:\Docs\excel0001.xls"
Elseif Asset = "2" Then
    AssetURL = "X:\Docs\excel0002.xls"
End If

Range("C1").Value = AssetURL
```

Comment: Is the code block with a `Sub` or a `Function`?

Comment: The problem is not in this code. Please show the WHOLE module code.

Comment: I didnt want to put it in a Sub as I want to use it for different Subs, will I need to put it in a function?

Comment: If you put the code within a **Sub,** other subs can call it! The logic is not suitable for a **Function**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to ensure you can run your code within multiple Subs is to make it a `Public Sub`:

```
Public Sub qwerty()
    Dim Asset As String, AssetURL As String

    Asset = Range("B1").Value

    If Asset = "1" Then
        AssetURL = "X:\Docs\excel0001.xls"
    ElseIf Asset = "2" Then
        AssetURL = "X:\Docs\excel0002.xls"
    End If

    Range("C1").Value = AssetURL
End Sub
```

When you want to execute this code elsewhere, you should use:

```
Sub OtherSub()
    'OtherSub Code
    Call qwerty() 'or just qwerty
    'Rest of OtherSub Code
End Sub
```

[Related question on using `Call` to utilize a `Sub` within another `Sub`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479891/what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6)