# VBA - Call Excel Object in Function from Add-in

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel Object named ThisWorkbook and a Module named Module1. In Module1, I have a function called function1. ThisWorkbook has a private sub called sub1. When user call this function, I want Excel to do sub1 first and if it has no error, perform the rest of the function. However, I am unable to process sub1 when call function1.

**Excel Object - ThisWorkbook**

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Public Sub sub1(some parameters)
...
If (condition) Then
  Msgbox ()
End If
...
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set App = Application
End Sub
```

**Excel Module - Module1**

```
Function function1(Add As String, some parameters) As String
    ThisWorkbook.sub1(some parameters)
    ...
End Function
```

** updated frequently to show the current state of code

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.sub1` instead of `Call sub1`.

Comment: `Sub1` needs to be `Public`, not `Private`

Comment: Hi @Rory, it has been set to Public (as updated) but still unable to call.

Comment: If you use parentheses when calling it, you must use `Call`: `Call ThisWorkbook.sub1(some parameters)`. Otherwise, remove the parentheses: `ThisWorkbook.sub1 some, parameters`

Comment: Remove the parentheses, it looked like this - App_SheetSelectionChange ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range - but it still did not work. Tried the first method of calling, both compiled errors are syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Sub1` is within the scope of `ThisWorkbook` and not in a global module you need to specify that in your call:

```
Call ThisWorkbook.Sub1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to refer to a sub, which is in `ThisWorkbook`, you should refer to the `ThisWorkbook` as well like this:

`ThisWorkbook.sub1` instead of `Call sub1`.

Comment: Hi, does private sub affects the call? I tried both private and public sub sub1 but they gives me compiled error - syntax error.

Comment: @Eddie - hi, it does not. `Call` is a bit old way for programming in VBA, and it is a good idea to avoid it, if you can - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479891/what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6 It can cause you some troubles, if you are using arguments, due to the way it refers to them.

Comment: Hi @Vityata, I removed Call but it still did not work - syntax error. This is the sub I want to call ThisWorkbook.App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range). I have put both "ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range" in my function input parameters.

Comment: @Eddie - if you remove the call, then the parameters should be passed without parenthesis.

Comment: I have removed the parenthesis - ThisWorkbook.App_SheetSelectionChange ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, the error is syntax error. When I remove parameter - ThisWorkbook.App_SheetSelectionChange and the error is "Argument not optional".

Comment: @Eddie - remove the parenthesis when you call the function, not when you build it.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is the parenthesis is removed when call function. The sub1 still has parenthesis and parameters.

Comment: @Eddie - so your question should be actually, "How to fire the built-in `SheetSelectionChange` event in VBA?"

Comment: I am not sure, what I intend to do is to call the SheetSelectionChange under Excel Object in Add-in to a function under Module in Add-in; to do SheetSelectionChange first, if no msgbox then do the rest of the function.