# Calling Macro from inside Macro - Error Compile Error: Expected variable or procedure, not module - Private Sub App

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word, word-2013

I have been copying code moslty to work on and learn macro's in Word. I have got it working where I can get a MsgBox to appear before printing, but I would like it to call another module/macro to compartmentalize the modules.

For testing, this works:

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox "Before Print"
End Sub
```

But if I do:

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
Call Greeting
End Sub
```

Which is a working macro that I have which simple opens a MsgBox and says "Greetings", I get the following error:

```
Compile Error: Expected variable or procedure, not module
```

**How can I call another Macro inside this Private Sub App*?**

Comment: Absolutely to be honest. I revised a deleted post to hopefully get myself out of a question ban and posted the solution  to my question. Hopefully thought the screenshots will help others understand the issue.

Comment: Seems that using the word Call has caused your Q to be misunderstood.   If you edit the Q to make it clear what you actually mean (include that your Module and Function names were the same) I'll consider reopening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this post has been covered before, I will share the answer here as well in case others land here.

The issue is that you can't have a module named the same as a sub. See Screenshot below for what is WRONG!

[image]

Interestingly, if you put the sub that calls the other sub (greeting) inside the same module (greeting) it works! But I would say this is bad practice and should be avoided. See example below:

[image]

I will generally just append `_Sub` to my module names to avoid this issue like below:

[image]

Also a note about using the keyword `Call`.

> You are not required to use the Call keyword when calling a procedure.
> However, if you use the Call keyword to call a procedure that requires
> arguments, argumentlist must be enclosed in parentheses. If you omit
> the Call keyword, you also must omit the parentheses around
> argumentlist. If you use either Call syntax to call any intrinsic or
> user-defined function, the function's return value is discarded.

See here for more information --> [What does the Call keyword do in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479891/what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6)